# MVC 3.0 JQUERY Partial page update

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've a JQuery UI Date Picker. Upon selection of the date, the data on graph changes.

The issue is that when I select the date on the date picker, whole page refreshes and data gets populated.

Is there anyway, I can just update the graph which is on  tag? Note, upon selection of the date, jquery posts to server and gets the new data for selected date.

I'm using  `$.ajax({ });` to make a call to the server. I would have thought this will do a trick but it is not the case.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might need to implement ajax function to update the graph to avoid the page refresh. How do you update the graph? At server side?

Comment: Graph gets updated using JSON and knockout.js. Would be nice if there's anyway I can hook up the data picker with KO.

Comment: If it gets updated from JSON source via javascript, you might not need ajax. Try adding "return false;" at the end of the function you update the graph. It will prevent postback event to server.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonas-Thein but the request will need to hit the server. I wanted to have a partial page update so that whole page doesn't get refreshed even though the request has been made to server behind the scene.

Comment: I've used  $.ajax({ still gets refreshed.

Comment: Can you post some markup and your js calls in the question.

Comment: Could you put some of the code as you send the data by ajax and html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#datepickerid').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
     $.ajax({ ... } );
     return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I don`t know the name of your methods, divs, just change accordingly if this helps.
Try something as follows:

```
        $("#DateDiv").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst)
        {
            UpdateGraph(dateText);
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) 
        { 
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "@Url.Action("LoadGraph", "YourController")",
                data:
                {
                    date: new Date(year, month - 1, 1).toString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
$("#UpdateGraphDataDiv").html(data);
                                   },
                error: function (request, status, error)
                {
                    DisplayErrorMessageBox(ParseErrorFromResponse(request.responseText, "Unknown error"), true);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need something like

```
$('button').click(function(event){ 
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({ ... } );
});
```